# Copying and Editing Jenkins Jobs

Tags: jenkins

I have been using Jenkins for a couple of months now, and have been able to set up a simple CI system.
I currently have a build tab - that will build and deploy 25 different components successfully, based on building from an SVN trunk.

I'm now taking my first branch - some people will develop on the trunk and some will develop fixes on the branch.

I would now like to have CI up and running for both branch and trunk - so would create a second tab - with a repeat of the jobs from the first tab, but this time changing the SVN path to check out from the branch.

As I have rather a lot of jobs and the task is quite repetitive, is there an easy way to do this ? I'm hoping that each job tab might be a single xml that I can edit / rename to give me a second tab ?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, each job **is** as single xml file, located under `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/$JOB_NAME/config.xml`. However there are a number of places in the `config.xml` that reference it's location, so simply copy-pasting the actual file isn't the best option.

Jenkins UI itself has "copy job" function.

- Click "New Item" where you want it
- Select "Copy existing Item"
- Specify the name of existing item to copy
- Specify the name for the new job
- Then go to configure the new job and change what you need.

**Another tip:** may not apply to your setup, but more often than not, there is a "unifying difference" between multiple similar jobs, most often a branch name, or project name, or similar. The value would be that only one that needs to change between otherwise identical jobs, however that changed value may appear several times within the job configuration.

I usually make a "choice" parameter, with a single choice, and put that different value there. The rest of the job references the choice param as a variable. So when I copy identical jobs, I just need to change that 1 value at the top of job configuration page. Everything else falls into place.

Comment: I wonder why ppl dont upvote or praise much over SO. Isn't SO has anything to do with karma.

Comment: @Iqra. actually "thank you" posts are discouraged by SO rules. Upvotes are always welcome ;)

Comment: Your post wasn't a |thank you| post, it was a detailed and helpful one.